# Political affiliation discrimination, a one word answer

Tags: single-word-requests

Politics: When a person discriminates on sex they are sexist, race we call it racism, what is called when someone discriminates based on a political party?

Comment: The word **dogmatism** was not proposed in the potential duplicate. It means *unfounded positiveness in matters of opinion; arrogant assertion of opinions as truths*.

Comment: *discernment*. [facetious]

Answer (score 0):

Such discrimination is called "partisanship."